# SSIS : How to pick analysis service components failed status in script task using c#

Tags: c#, ssis, ssas

Problem Statement:

In SSIS package, i have build the package which will execute the SSAS cube using Analysis processing and data sync task. Once these two task completed then it will start to run the Script task which will pick recent data subscriptions from our SharePoint site then it will send it to end users through send mail task.

I need a help on the below scenario,

If suppose any of the two analysis services(Processing or Data Sync Task) got failed i need to capture that failure status in Script task with failure time.

This will help me to pick the failed time subscriptions when i will restart my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnError handlers, set a couple of package-level variables with the error message and the time.   Then reference those variables in your script task.